# Hand getting excessively extended when bench pressing with bulldog grip

Tags: bench-press

I've been benchpressing with the normal grip, and it hasn't been going so well, so I started to switch to bulldog grip. Now, the new issue I face is that I am experiencing quite a bunch of hand extension. That is, when I bench press my hand is getting over-extended. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

When doing any bench press grip you want to rotate you hands forward to have the back of your hand parallel to your forearm. The bar should be resting on the heel of your hand/the pad of your thumb. When looking from the side you should see the bar basically see the bar basically directly above your wrist. Having your wrist extended backwards will feel easier but rotating so the bar is directly above your wrist will be safer and make bench press slightly stronger due to better form.

Comment: OP is doing bulldog grip, so this answer is not applicable. -1.